# C#, JSON Parsing, dynamic variable. How to check type?

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net, typechecking

I'm parsing JSON texts. Sometimes I get `Array` and sometimes `Object` types in the text. I tried to check the type as follows:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);  //json text
if (obj is Array)
{  
    Console.WriteLine("ARRAY!");
}
else if (obj is Object)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OBJECT!");
}
```

I checked the types while debugging. `obj` had `Type` property as `Object` when parsing objects and `Array` when parsing arrays. However the console output was `OBJECT!` for both situations. Obviously I'm checking the type in a wrong manner. What is the correct way to check the type?

**EDIT**

JSON contents:

`[ {"ticket":"asd", ...}, {..} ]` or `{ "ASD":{...}, "SDF":{...} }`

In both situations I get the output as `OBJECT!`.

**EDIT#2**

I changed the typechecking order as @Houssem suggested. Still the same output. Therefore I changed the OP as well. My code is like this right now, and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this, since the JSON.NET return an object of type JToken

```
  if (((JToken)obj).Type == JTokenType.Array)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ARRAY!");
  }
  else if (((JToken)obj).Type == JTokenType.Object)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("OBJECT!");
  }
```